# Split string list according to the second delimeter

Tags: python, string, list

given I have a string list like this:

```
<class 'list'>: ['a;b;c', '9;6;0.4', '9;2;0.6', '10;7;0.3', '10;8;0.7']
```

How can I use split to split it according to the second ";" to this format:

```
<class 'list'>: ['a;b', '9;6', '9;2', '10;7', '10;8']
```

Thank you very much!.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Its duplicated. Please delete!

Answer (score 0):

Use split along with list comprehension.

It appears as though you just have to remove the last item separated by a ";" for each string in the list.

Therefore, you should do something along the lines of this:

```
> y = ['a;b;c', '9;6;0.4', '9;2;0.6', '10;7;0.3', '10;8;0.7']
> x = [';'.join(x.split(";")[0:2]) for x in y]
> x
['a;b', '9;6', '9;2', '10;7', '10;8']
```

This will work if you just have to remove the last element that is in the string.

Answer (score 0):

This strategy should work and you can figure out syntax.
1. Loop over the list
2. For each item in the list use string.lastindexof() to find position of last ";". 
3. Then use String.substring(0,) to get what you want